# How to reference one cell from an array in a condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to do a counting of the number of strings that match a given string in microsoft excel. For example, if I have

String to be matched - 'apple'

and an array as follows - 
'apple'
'banana'
'apple'
'pear'
'mango'
'apple'

I want excel to return 3 as apple occurs 3 times. I am using COUNTIF for doing this, but cannot figure out how to give condition such that I can say ith element = given string (similar to how we do in writing code on c/java). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your "array" has elements in different cells? Then use COUNTIF ...or it's everything is in a single cell?

Comment: They are in different cells

Comment: yass already answered you then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean your Data in column A (A1:A6),

```
Column A  
    apple  
    banana  
    apple
    pear
    mango
    apple
```

In B1 write:

```
=Countif(A1:A6,"apple")
```

or

```
=Countif($A$1:$A$6,A1)
```

Comment: Could you give link to a resource that explains how referencing in such situations works. Eg: if I want to calculate the no. of cells empty in given range.

Comment: =COUNTIF(A1:A9,"") will count empty cells ""  [countif](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)

Answer (score 1):

`COUNTIF()` is great if the data is spread out over several cells, but if we have:

[image]

Then use:

```
=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,A1,"")))/LEN(A1)
```

Comment: ...Damn you smart guy! ;-D

Comment: @danicotra ...........I did not invent this.........all I did was remember it.......

Comment: I know yours is not the answer here but... I couldn't not upvote it anyway! :-)